# Could a lamp plugged into an outlet be dimmed using a variable resistor?

Tags: potentiometer, mains, dimming

If you had a variable resistor connected between a lamp and the wall, could it be dimmed with a variable resistor?

Would it be practical, i.e. would it waste much energy? And would it affect both current and voltage or only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; this was how it was done before triac dimmers became available. Usually known as a "rheostat".

The sum of energy dissipated in lamp + dissipated in resistor is then constant, so you need a 60W resistor.

Both voltage and current would be affected together; the lightbulb is an ohmic resistor.

Comment: I can't find any options like this in stores though. Are there any short male-to-male plugs with this feature?

Comment: No, the total power (not energy) is not constant.  As the resistor in series increases, the total power goes down.

Comment: @DarkLightA - I very much doubt you will find any nowadays; it's an obsolete technology, way too inefficient for todays energy conscious society. Any reason why you can't use a standard triac dimmer?

Comment: I was thinking about using it to dim things that don't come with a dimmer.

Comment: Dimming incandescent lights does not save a lot of energy, though it does prolong filament life. The problem is that the light output (lumens) drops off rapidly with a slight reduction of wattage. By dimming lights, you're turning high wattage light sources into slightly lower wattage heat sources. It is more efficient to use a lower wattage bulb, than to use a higher wattage bulb to produce the same amount of light by dimming it. The higher wattage incandescent bulb, turned down, will have a lower color temperature, wasting more energy as heat.

Comment: Nope. Before triac dimmers they used **variacs**, not rheostats.

Answer (score 1):

As pjc50 mentioned, in past resistive regulators were used to control dimming and speed regulation of fans.

Although a rheostat can be used to regulate a mains device but it was expensive and brought up the costs. To lower the cost, a multi tap resistor was used.

This resistive setup is not practical these days as triacs can be used to accomplish that. Triac based dimmers waste lot less energy compared to the resistive regulator.

In picture below a regulator with multi-tap resistors is shown
[image: fan regulator with resistors]

In the picture below, a multi-tap resistor is shown.
[image: multi tap resistor]

A Practical triac based regulator is shown below
[image: triac regulator]

A basic circuit of triac based regulator is here
[image]

Answer (score -4):

Thats true....rheostat can be used but they dont give u full potential or full control over the brightness of lamp....You can use a pwm circuit(555 pwm circuits are popular) and a 300V mosfet.....it will do the trick...But i guess it wont work for AC....Dont know exactly....will let u know..